# How to delete folders older than 30 days based and based off of name

Tags: bash, ip

I have a Syslog server that I collect log files from the internet. My configuration creates a new folder and Syslog file based off of the incoming IP address.

So in my /var/log folder I have folders that are IP addresses

- 123.234.124.123
- 123.234.14.13
- 123.22.124.123 etc..

I have a command that will delete them all but It is not specific enough

```
rm -fr `ls | grep -E [0-9]{3}`
```

This is too loose if I have a directory that is "345" and it should not be deleted by my script.

I have tried

```
rm -fr `ls | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b"
```

but I think the syntax is incorrect.  Once I have it only delete the folders that are like IP addresses I will then work on the age of the folders as well.

Any advice?

Comment: `sudo apt install zsh` `zsh` `ls <0-255>.<0-255>.<0-255>.<0-255>`  `exit`  Bash probably has a way of doing this too, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

I think something similar to this should do it.  In addition to finding directories with IP-type names, it will also delete only those directories older than 30 days.

```
find . -type d -regextype egrep -regex "./[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}" -mtime +30 | xargs rm -rf
```

Explanation of arguments:

- `type d` - Only list directories
- `regextype` - Use the egrep flavor when defining the regex
- `regex` - Defines a regex to use (I found one that matches IP addresses)
- `mtime` - Only list directories older than 30 days
- `xargs rm -rf` - Rid yourself of the directories listed

Answer (score 0):

Based on your regex (there are better ones you can find on stackoverflow for IP addresses):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype egrep -regex '.*([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b?$' -exec rm {} +
```

Alternately, since you might want to do further processing, it could be better to pipe, replacing rm with whatever you want to do.  Check out the man page for xargs and `-I`/`-i`in particular if you want to examine each file:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype egrep -regex '.*([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b?$' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Also, I think "-maxdepth 1" is specific to GNU find, but most versions have equivalents.  It keeps it from going recursive--the default behavior.